# Paypal in-context express checkout - modal windows incorrect

Tags: .net, paypal, sdk, express-checkout

I integrated  Paypal express checkout in my project. All fine!  Then I tried to switch to "In-Context Checkout", but the redirect page is allways paypal home page, never the classic paypal login page to pay or new layout (responsive for mobile payments).

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In paypal documentation (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/) I read: "Update your redirect URL to: https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/" 
Thi is wrong, imho, because I use redirect_url parameter in response of my  "create checkout" request.
So, We need to replace redirect_url with 
www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/?cmd=_express-checkout&token=[TOKEN].

This is valid for live environment, but what appens in sandbox? I tried and seems it is not possible to use in-context checkout in sandbox environment.

Comment: ever figured this out? I too am having similar problems

Comment: Hello.You can try to use this sintax to return redirect url:  redirectUrl = payment.links.First(l => l.rel == "approval_url").href